# error on using exec() to call python script in browser

Tags: php, python, exec

I am trying to call a python script by php:

```
<?php
    $a = exec("python ~/www/encrypt.py");
    echo $a;
?>
```

I use terminal and `php index.php` command to see result and it works well but in a web browser it does not show anything.

**Problem solved** by full path >> `exec("python /var/www/encrypt.py");`

Comment: does encrypt.py actually print anything to stdout?

Comment: Check that your Apache (or other webserver) user has relevant privileges to run python... and give your python script argument a real filepath rather than ~ which is variable depending on the logged in user... from a web browser, ~ will be relative to your apache process user

Comment: In addition to what Mark said, give the full path to `python`.

Comment: You should also make sure that the webserver actually finds the `python` interpreter itself - better use the absolute path like `/usr/bin/python` instead of `python` (or call the `.py` script directly and add a `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top)

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by full path.